# Wrong element height from a Directive with jQuery

Tags: javascript, jquery, angularjs, angularjs-directive

I'm new to Angular and I'm trying to do some DOM calculations and manipulations from Directive using jQuery. What I've got however is wrong height of my element. In my case the element is something like container - so the height almost all the viewport height.

```
directives.directive('responsiveAlerts', ['$log', '$window', function ($log, $window) {
    return {
        restrict: 'A',
        compile: function (element, attributes) {
            console.log($('.page').height());
        }
    };
}]);
```

I've got 46 as a height, which is wrong. When I type in the console:

```
$('.container').height();
```

since the page is loaded - I'm getting the right height of my container. 
Has anybody have idea why there is such a difference ?

many thanks in advance!

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The `compile` method of a directive runs before angular links all the templates and renders them. You will see this, if you put a breakpoint at the line with `console.log`. The browsers window will be almost empty then and the registered height is therefor correct.

If you need the correct height of the page, put a `$watch` on it and handle it, whenever it changes:

```
directives.directive('responsiveAlerts', ['$log', '$window', function ($log, $window) {
  return {
    restrict: 'A',
    link: function ($scope) {
        var elPage = angular.element('.page');
        $scope.$watch(elPage.height, function () {
             console.log(elPage.height());
        }
    }
  };
}]);
```

Comment: Actually, I believe this is the right answer for using `$timeout` ;)

Comment: If you need to continuously monitor changes to the node's height (on window resize, for example), and can handle the performance hit, use  `$watch`.  If you only need to do something based on the height when the element is first drawn, use a zero-duration `$timeout` instead.

Comment: Thanks for those. You right - this has no place in compile function.
with $timeout I can get the height of the container. I'm not sure what I'll get with $watch however. I have overlay popup, which is initialy empty on page load and I need his height. Initial it has negative height, which is not real one. At some moment this overlay shows and then I need his height. I tried your code and it comes with some value on $watch, which I'm not sure is real one as well.

Comment: The solution with `$timeout` may be the most appropriate one. The difference to the `$watch` solution is, that with `$timeout` you get the height once, after your template has been rendered. with `$watch` you get it, whenever the elements height changes.

Comment: `directives.directive('responsiveAlerts', ['$window', function ($window) {
          return {
            restrict: "A",
            link: function(scope, element, attr) {
                var el = angular.element(element);
                scope.$watch(el.height, function() {
                    console.log(el.height());
                });
            }
          };
        }]);`
dialog template has:

`<div ng-show="isActive.active == true" class="overlay-wrapper">
    <div responsive-alerts>
        <h1>...</h1>
        <p>...</p>
        
    </div>
</div>`

Comment: After template is rendered I have wrong height - console says (30), on 
`$('.my-dialog').height()`

it gives me -40 or something. When this dialog appears and has come content the height is different and this is the real height that I need,  but the scope.$watch in this case doesn't output anything. 
After the dialog appears and I try his height with jQuery from the console as above - it gives me the real height.

Can I watch / get this real height in my directive?