# xsl:for-each Getting the current() node attribute

Tags: xml, foreach, xslt-1.0

I have a question about xsl:for-each loop:

I have something like

```
<hodeName>
    <nodeChild name='name1'>value</nodeChild>
    <nodeChild name='name2'>value</nodeChild>
    <nodeChild name='name3'/>
</hodeName>
```

I want to loop over them, name a variable with attribute name and assign it the value. 
I'm struggling with something like

```
<xsl:for-each select="/root/nodeName">
    <json:string name="{current()/@name}"><xsl:value-of select="current()" /></json:string>
</xsl:for-each>
```

Which doesn't work. It is assigning however the correct xsl:value-of.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

**Why your approach does not work**

You are defining a sequence to be processed by `for-each` like the following:

```
<xsl:for-each select="/root/nodeName">
```

But if you compare this to your input XML, there is no outermost element that is called `root`. The outermost element is called `hodeName`. Perhaps you thought `/root` was a special keyword in XSLT to refer to the root of the document? That's not the case. `root` is just a normal XML element. `/` itself, when at the beginning of an XPath expression, means the *root* or *document node*.

---

Another approach would use several templates instead of `for-each`. "Looping over" something is a concept more related to procedural languages, not declarative, functional languages like XSLT. Applying templates is the *XSLT-onic* (perhaps you know Python?) way of doing it.

Are you sure the outermost element should be called `hodeName` instead of `nodeName`?

**Stylesheet**

```
<xsl:stylesheet xmlns:xsl="http://www.w3.org/1999/XSL/Transform" version="1.0"
   xmlns:json="http://json.org/">

   <xsl:output method="xml" indent="yes"/>
   <xsl:strip-space elements="*"/>          

   <xsl:template match="hodeName">
       <json:object>
           <xsl:apply-templates/>
       </json:object>
   </xsl:template>

   <xsl:template match="nodeChild">
       <json:string name="@name">
           <xsl:value-of select="."/>
       </json:string>
   </xsl:template>

</xsl:stylesheet>
```

**XML Output**

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>
<json:object xmlns:json="http://json.org/">
   <json:string name="@name">value</json:string>
   <json:string name="@name">value</json:string>
   <json:string name="@name"/>
</json:object>
```

Comment: Thanks for this detailed explanation. You probably right by adding more declarative approach as this is xsl. About the root element - no I just replaced original values from my document to simplify it a bit.

Comment: @Vladyn You are welcome. Next time you are asking a question, make sure you do not edit out relevant information (the `root` element appears in your code, but not in the input XML). And be sure to [_accept an answer_](http://meta.stackexchange.com/questions/5234/how-does-accepting-an-answer-work) (not necessarily mine), also for [your last question](http://stackoverflow.com/a/24513625/1987598).

Answer (score 3):

You are selecting `/root/nodeName` instead of `/hodeName/nodeChild` as your XML suggests. Otherwise it seems to work.

```
<xsl:stylesheet xmlns:xsl="http://www.w3.org/1999/XSL/Transform"
                xmlns:json="http://json.org/"
                version="1.0">
   <xsl:template match="/">
     <json:object>
       <xsl:for-each select="/hodeName/nodeChild">
         <json:string name="{current()/@name}"><xsl:value-of select="current()" /></json:string>
       </xsl:for-each>
     </json:object>
   </xsl:template>
</xsl:stylesheet>
```

Also, you don't need to specify `current()` unless it is the only expression. `@name` is equivalent to `current()/@name`.

Comment: many thanks for clarifying this reference between current() and it's node attribute by simply adding @name.

Comment: Actually I still can't get in to this loop assigning the variable name dynamically:

    <json:object name="document">
        <xsl:for-each select="/document">
            <json:string name="@name"><xsl:value-of select="current()" /></json:string>
        </xsl:for-each>
    </json:object>


Which loops over: 

    <document>
 <config name='n1'>1</config>
 <config name='n2'>2</config>
 <config name='n3'/>
    </document>

The __current()__ gives me the right value, but I can't assign the ring variable name in JSON like: 

    {"n1": "1"....}

Comment: `select="/document"` selects the root element, of which there is only one. Use `select="/document/config"` to loop over the `<config>` elements instead. (And use back-ticks (`) to quote inline code)

Comment: `select="document/config"` is the right way definitely, but I'm still can't set the variable name dynamically: 

`<xsl:for-each select="/document/config">
    <json:string name="@name"><xsl:value-of select="current()" /></json:string>
</xsl:for-each>` 

where `@name` I need to get the value of name attribute and create a json string with that name and assign it the value of `current()`